# Batchclass How to get start variable in execute method

Tags: apex, batch

I want to get the metaapi variable in the execute method.

```
global static IntelligratedAPI__mdt metaapi = new IntelligratedAPI__mdt();
public String query;

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    metaapi = [select id,endpoint__c,days__c,runonce__c from IntelligratedAPI__mdt where qualifiedApiName ='GetHID' limit 1 ];
    if(metaapi.runonce__c == true){
        query = 'Select ID, email from user where FederationIdentifier =Null';
    }else{
        query = 'Select ID, email from user where FederationIdentifier =Null and createddate >= LAST_N_DAYS:'+metaapi.days__c;
    }
    return  Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<user> records) { 
   // metaapi = [select id,endpoint__c,days__c,runonce__c from IntelligratedAPI__mdt where qualifiedApiName ='GetHID' limit 1 ];
    system.debug('meta'+metaapi.endpoint__c);

 }
```

Is it correct? Because i am not getting the metaapi printed in debug.

Answer (score 1):

To keep state between batch executions (and the start method), you need to annotate your class with the `Database.Stateful` interface. That interface is just a marker to tell Salesforce to maintain the state, it doesn't require you to implement any methods.

Then, you need to make your `metaapi` an instance variable, not static. From the docs:

> If you specify `Database.Stateful` in the class definition, you can
>   maintain state across these transactions. When using
>   `Database.Stateful`, only instance member variables retain their values
>   between transactions. **Static member variables don’t retain their**
>   **values** and are reset between transactions.

[Emphasis mine]

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_maintain_state

Answer (score -1):

Below are the Points. Kindly check it.

1. You are returning a string (Query) value from the Start method. Here, you need to return the Query (metaapi) to the Execute method. (Reason: The return value of a SOQL query or an Iterator should be passed as a parameter to the Execute method)
2. In the Execute method, you are extracting a List value.
   ***metaapi.endpoint__c*** - If this is a single Object reference, your code is correct. If not, run a for loop and then get the desired Field value.

In the above code, you are returning a "String" from the 'start method' and you are trying to get a "Query field value" in the debug console from the 'Execute method'. That is why you are not able to get the desired output.

Comment: The code presented by the OP doesn't return a String from the start method, but a QueryLocator. Never return MDT records from the start method of a batch! In 2024 they are cached and don't require queries at all. As for the execute method: The OP clearly stated it doesn't work. And there is a concise answer explaining why. A for loop wouldn't help. Anyway, the question is 5 years old and the asking person haven't been around for years.

Comment: This answer is incorrect on multiple levels.